# Google Map inside jquery tab issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show a google map inside a jquery tab. My code is working but not rendering map inside tab, i have applied all techniques given in various questions posted on stackoverflow but none of them seems to be working. Below is my code

css

```
.tab_container { }
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 100%;}

    ul.tabs li  {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 31px;
        line-height: 31px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-left: none;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        background: #e0e0e0 url(images/accordion_header.png) repeat-x top right;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative; }   
        ul.tabs li a        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #222;
            display: block;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            padding: 0 20px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            outline: none;  }
    ul.tabs li a:hover { background: #ccc; }    
            ul.tabs li.active, ul.tabs li.active a:hover  { background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }

.tab_content_container {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;}
    .tab_content { font-size: 1.2em; padding: 20px 20px 10px; display: none; }  
    .tab_content:first-child { display: block; }
```

jquery function

```
(function($){
    $.fn.tabs = function(options) { 
        var defaults = {};  
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  
        return this.each( function() {          
            var $tabContainer = $(this);
            var $tabLi = $tabContainer.find ('.tabs li');
            var $tabContent = $tabContainer.find ('.tab_content');          
            $tabContent.hide ();
            $tabLi.eq (0).addClass ('active').show ();
            $tabContent.eq (0).show ();

            $tabLi.live ('click' , function () 
            {
                var activeTab = $(this).find ('a').attr ('href');

                $tabLi.removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $tabContent.hide ();
                $(activeTab).css({'visibility':'visible'});                 
                $tabContainer.find (activeTab).fadeIn ('slow');
                if(activeTab == '#about') {
                        initialize();//google map
                      }
                return false;
            });         });         };

})(jQuery);
function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.46583740, 77.03269809999999);
      var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        });    
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
            marker.setMap(map);
        }); 
    }
```

here is HTML div

```
<div id="about" class="tab_content" style="display: none; "> 
                                        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: is the map_canvas element inside the tab?

Comment: set up a jsfiddle or jsbin so we can see your attempts and edit your code.

Comment: inside the tab make sure div is visible before init a map

Comment: yes map_canvas is inside the tab, i have edited the code to include those lines as well. div should be visible befor init of map. I will setup jsfiddle soon and update you all

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng  //<----- remove the ' , '
 });
```

see if works.